# How to confirm successful bug report in Debian reportbug?

Tags: debian, reportbug

My system may not have correctly configured SMTP and other settings. 
I still tried to send a bug report by `reportbug` in Debian 9. 
I did not find any list of current bug reports in the Debian listings. 
I want to confirm that the submission of the bug report is successful by `reportbug` itself.

I think the following setting page is the problem. No email  `reportbug` i.e. reporting bug and waiting a few minutes, when having Thunderbird only in my system. Failure because Thunderbird is not MTA, but it is an MUA (sourcejedi).

> Do you have a mail transport agent (MTA) like Exim, Postfix or SSMTP configured on this computer to send mail to the Internet?

OS: Debian 9.1

Comment: The Debian BTS will acknowledge that your bug report has been successfully received by assigning it a number. And then you can read that bug report online by going to `bugs.debian.org/bugnumber`. I suppose you can look up all the bug reports for that package via `reportbug`, but I don't understand the significance of reportbug here. Why do you want to restrict yourself to that particular piece of software?

Comment: First configure the reportbug tool : `reportbug --configure` then test it

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 As I recall, you tell reportbug you are reporting a bug for some package, and then it gives an option to list the bugs for that package, though it isn't a particularly useful option unless you are running in console mode. What does Dvorak have to do with this?

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영  choose yes , if you have thunderbird already configured

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 If you didn't get the bug id number, then most probably your bug report didn't reach the BTS. Did you test it? I think the `--debug` flag can be used for that.

Comment: Choose No, Thunderbird is not an MTA, it is an MUA, you do not have an MTA unless you have configured Exim, or installed and configured Postfix or SSMTP, etc.

Comment: Also, Debian will mail you confirmation of the bug, so if you don't have an email within ten minutes or so, _something_ is going wrong (it could be you typo'd the email address to reportbug, or some part of the debian infrastructure is down for maintenance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate and send a report bud manually according to [Sending the bug report via e-mail](https://www.debian.org/Bugs/Reporting)

> You can report bugs in Debian by sending an e-mail to  **submit@bugs.debian.org**  with a special format described below. reportbug [(see above)](https://www.debian.org/Bugs/Reporting#reportbug) will properly format the e-mails for you; please use it!

You can generate a reportbug manually through `reportbug` command , e,g:

```
reportbug --template --bts debian -S normal console-setup
```

> If you have reportbug installed the output of `reportbug -q --template -T none -s none -S normal -b --list-cc none -q <package>` will also be useful, as it contains the output of maintainer specific scripts and version information.

Copy it to thunderbird then Answer the 4 questions , send it.

```
*** Reporter, please consider answering these questions, where appropriate ***

  * What led up to the situation?
   * What exactly did you do (or not do) that was effective (or
     ineffective)?
   * What was the outcome of this action?
   * What outcome did you expect instead?
```

Also you can install `postfix` or `exim4` ... , then configure it :

```
dpkg-reconfigure postfix
dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config
```

Comment: This doesn't acknowledge the question asked, but it's a very useful suggestion e.g. for GMail users who don't want to "Allow less secure apps to access your account" (i.e. software that doesn't implement OAuth).

Answer (score 1):

Debian will mail you confirmation of the bug report, including the assigned bug number.  So if you don't have an email after waiting fifteen minutes, *something* is going wrong.   (Although it could be a mistake in the email address you gave to `reportbug`, or that some part of the Debian infrastructure is down for maintenance).

In order to have "a mail transport agent (MTA) like Exim, Postfix or SSMTP configured on [your] computer to send mail to the Internet", you would have had to configure it yourself, and also test that it works.  So if you're unsure whether you have that... it's fairly clear that you don't.

EDIT: Simply accept the defaults for every option, and reportbug will submit bugs directly to the Debian servers.

Or use the alternative method suggested by GAD3R.

Alternatively, you can configure `reportbug` with your internet SMTP server, just like you configured Thunderbird.  `reportbug` differs in that it does not have a config wizard that knows the values needed for common providers, although they are not *too* hard to find.  However, if you use the most popular email provider, you will have to *either* ["Allow less secure apps to access your account"](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en), *or* switch to two-factor authentication and then generate an "application specific password" for `reportbug` to use.  The latter approach is very similar to what the "more secure" OAuth does behind the scenes.  I use the former approach - it's not a problem if you're somehow sure that the "less secure" apps you use are not *storing* the password - and reportbug asks me for the password each time I use it.

---

Do not try to configure an MTA just for `reportbug`.  Unless you already understood and would remember that this MTA would probably not work for many other purposes!  Because running an MTA *and getting the world to accept your mail from it* is a professional job, requiring periodic maintenance.  For example there is an unmaintained series of Ars Technica articles on self-hosting email from 2014; it looks like [part 3 of 4](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/03/taking-e-mail-back-part-3-fortifying-your-box-against-spammers/) discusses aspects like DKIM.

If you did have such an MTA configured, you might check your local inbox for bounce messages, then escalate to checking the MTA log files.

Comment: So using GAD3R's answer in the end is the right thing to do, I think, so manual sending of the bug report.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 yes, using GAD3R's command is fine.  I don't want to discourage anyone from configuring `reportbug` to use e.g. GMail's smtp server either, but IMO it's a bit more complex to understand _if_ you use GMail and would have to configure GMail to something that says its "less secure".