# Why Gnome 3.22 Assistive On Screen Keyboard supports only Qwerty?

Tags: debian, keyboard, gnome3, development

This thread is the continua of the thread [How to confirm successful bug report in Debian reportbug?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/388601/16920) because I could not file the bug report by `bugreport` in Debian.

Assistive technology > On Screen keyboard: only Qwerty seems to be supported

Problem: no Dvorak support, although using Dvorak keyboard

Fig. 1 When English Dvorak keyboard active, but showing Qwerty keyboard on the left-hand-side screen

[image]

The same amount of features on X11 and Wayland, so not a driver issue, but a lacking feature in the system.

OS: Debian 9.1
Window manager: Gnome 3.22